# How to load multiple tables from Amazon S3 to Amazon RedShift using AWS glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

I have a scenario in which my source data is in S3 and I need to load data into Amazon Redshift using AWS Glue. There are around 10 tables as my source but I was only able to load one table at a time using AWS glue studio. Is there any way, where I can load all the 10 tables from S3 TO Amazon RedShift in a single Job.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in a visual workflow, but the code you could use is `inputDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://your-bucket"], "recurse"=True}, format = "csv")`. The file format depends on your data type and you also need to import several libraries and write to Redshift. Let me know if this makes sense as it does require coding.